# Will there be a seventh season of The Americans?

Tags: the-americans

Will "The Americans" come back for Season 7? I have just finished watching the last episode of Season 6, when Philip and Elizabeth end up returning to their native country in Russia.

I asked this because the last episode does not make any sense to me. I believe there should be some sort of ending to close it.

Comment: "*the last episode does not make any sense to me*", really? One of the best ending of all TV shows, though...

Comment: But these two should have been arrested in USA soil, if this movie were in real life ?

Answer (score 2):

**No.**

In 2016, while Season 4 was airing, FX [announced](https://deadline.com/2016/05/the-americans-end-run-2-season-renewal-fx-seasons-5-6-1201762485/) that they were renewing *The Americans* for two further seasons, but that those seasons would be the last ones, with Season 6 serving as the finale. The show has therefore reached its intended conclusion and it is highly unlikely that any further episodes will be produced.

If you can't make sense of the final episode, I'd suggest asking a separate question about it.